# How to fix Javascript Timer In asp.net(Master Page concept)

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I Am trying to add Javascript timer in my asp.net project, it is implemented and runing as i needed, but if am pressing any key in that it is disappering for me. But Timer is runing.

Js. code

```
function myTimer(startVal, interval, outputId, dataField) {
         this.value = startVal;
         this.OutputCntrl = document.getElementById(outputId);
         this.currentTimeOut = null;
         this.interval = interval;
         this.stopped = false;
         this.data = null;
         var formEls = document.documentElement;
         if (dataField) {
             for (var i = 0; i < formEls.length - 1; i++) {
                 if (formEls[i].name == dataField) {
                     this.data = formEls[i];
                     i = formEls.length + 1;
                 }
             }
         }

         myTimer.prototype.go = function () {
             if (this.value > 0 && this.stopped == false) {
                 this.value = (this.value - this.interval);
                 if (this.data) {
                     this.data.value = this.value;
                 }
                 var current = this.value;
                 this.OutputCntrl.innerHTML = this.Hours(current) + ':' + this.Minutes(current) + ':' + this.Seconds(current);
                 this.currentTimeOut = setTimeout("Timer.go()", this.interval);
             }
             else {
                 alert('Time Out!');
                //window.location('Index.aspx');
             }



         }
         myTimer.prototype.stop = function () {
             this.stopped = true;
             if (this.currentTimeOut != null) {
                 clearTimeout(this.currentTimeout);
             }
         }
         myTimer.prototype.Hours = function (value) {
             return Math.floor(value / 3600000);
         }
         myTimer.prototype.Minutes = function (value) {
             return Math.floor((value - (this.Hours(value) * 3600000)) / 60000);
         }
         myTimer.prototype.Seconds = function (value) {
             var hoursMillSecs = (this.Hours(value) * 3600000)
             var minutesMillSecs = (this.Minutes(value) * 60000)
             var total = (hoursMillSecs + minutesMillSecs)
             var ans = Math.floor(((this.value - total) % 60000) / 1000);

             if (ans < 10)
                 return "0" + ans;

             return ans;
         }
     }
```

I'm calling it from button control.

Code

```
 void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string timerVal = Request.Form["timerData"];
    if (timerVal != null || timerVal == "")
    {
        timerVal = timerVal.Replace(",", String.Empty);
        timerStartValue = long.Parse(timerVal);
    }
}

private Int32 TimerInterval
{
    get
    {
        object o = ViewState["timerInterval"];
        if (o != null) { return Int32.Parse(o.ToString()); }
        return 50;
    }
    set { ViewState["timerInterval"] = value; }

}

 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


    StringBuilder bldr = new StringBuilder();
    bldr.AppendFormat("var Timer = new myTimer({0},{1},'{2}','timerData');", this.timerStartValue, this.TimerInterval, this.lblTimerCount.ClientID);
    bldr.Append("Timer.go()");
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "TimerScript", bldr.ToString(), true);
    ClientScript.RegisterHiddenField("timerData", timerStartValue.ToString());
}

void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StringBuilder bldr = new StringBuilder();
    bldr.AppendFormat("var Timer = new myTimer({0},{1},'{2}','timerData');", this.timerStartValue, this.TimerInterval, this.lblTimerCount.ClientID);
    bldr.Append("Timer.go()");
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "TimerScript", bldr.ToString(), true);
    ClientScript.RegisterHiddenField("timerData", timerStartValue.ToString());
}
```

I'M displaying it into Label control.

```
 <asp:Label ID="lblTimerCount" runat="server" Height="27px" 
                 Width="232px"></asp:Label>
```

**In Page_PreInit 'string timerVal' value is coming same after page_load which I'M passing, it starting timer from starting.?**

Please correct me.

Comment: Can you please explain why you have to do a full postback using the button in order to start the timer? The whole point of using javascript is that you can do it on the client and save the round trips to the server. You code-behind doesn't perform any other operations so it totally redundant.

Comment: Thnks chris , can you please correct me where i need to update the code. from button i need to start timer that why i'm calling javascript code.

Comment: Can't you use asp:Timer? It has a JavaScript API that you can use to start/stop and receive notifications.

Comment: Hi Peres, i wish to use it, but i need to show it as countdown timer, it should as digital clock time.

Answer (score 0):

These are the simple steps you need to follow:
1) upon page load, set the timerinterval on a hidden element

Your html should look like this:

```
<input type="button" id="btnStartTimer" name="StartTimer" value="Start" />
<input type="hidden" id="hdnInterval" name="Interval" value="50" />
<p>
    <label>Show Timer:</label>
    <label id="lblOutput"></label>
</p>

$('#YourButtonId').on('click', function(e){e.preventDefault; Timer.Go(); });
```

Your button js click event should look like this:

```
$('#btnStartTimer').on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var interval = $('#hdnInterval').val();
    var timer = new myTimer(0, interfal, "lblOutput", null);
    timer.go();
});
```

Something along those lines. This will make post backs unnecessary